# Receive an HTTP POST callback in an Angular application

Tags: angular, http, post, callback, http-post

I have an Angular application and I need to add some payment services to it. The Payment Service Provider (PSP) offers a Hosted Payment Page (HPP) where sensitive Credit Card information can be entered by our customers. From my Angular app, I redirect to the HPP using an URL that contains some encrypted information, such as the amount to be paid and the invoice number that is paid. Everything else is collected by this HPP (cardholder's name, address, credit card information, email address, etc.), and when the payment is processed, the HPP is trying to POST back the results of the payment request. The URL of the postback is also encrypted in the parameters used by the external URL of the HPP.

In my component, after the invoice is selected and the amount entered, I build this external URL and call

```
window.location.href = externalUrl;
```

The transfer to the HPP is done properly. I see the correct Invoice number and amount. I complete the payment but then I get an error in the browser when the call back is made: "Cannot POST /callback".

"/callback" is the route I defined in my Angular application. It is properly defined because I can navigate to it in the browser if I type it in the address bar. I can also verify in the network tab (DevTools) that the HPP is trying to post data back, as I see the Form Data in the Payload tab.

Doing some research, I found out that the component (or some other backend entity in my Angular application) needs to listen for POST requests on the /callback route. How do I do that?

I can post code from my callback component, but it is not much to it. In the ngOnInit I had this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    // Process the postback data here
    console.log("These are the parameters received: ", JSON.stringify(params))

    this.router.navigate(['/financial']);
  });
}
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

TIA, Ed

Edit 1: Not sure if relevant, but the flow of the application would be as follows: the customer selects an invoice in our application. The invoice has an amount to pay. We redirect the customer to the HPP, by providing the invoice number and the amount to pay. This is done by building an external URL that has a query parameter. The query parameter is nothing but the encryption of a string that contains many value-key pairs. Amongst them, it's the invoice number, the amount, a timestamp, and a callback URL.
The customer uses the HPP to enter personal and payment information and the PSP processes the payment. When the whole process is completed, the customer clicks a button that is supposed to return the control to our application, at the callback URL we have provided. Essentially, the browser will be redirected back to a page in our application Behind the scene, we would also receive the payment information which we would use to update the status of the invoice.

Comment: You would need to have a server-side handler for your `/callback` route. Is that an ajax request? or a full POST?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor I don't have an insight into the details of the PPS' HPP, but I can ask. I would guess that it is a full POST. The Integration Guide document I was given lacks any specifics on this postback call.

Comment: In ether case, you'd definitely have to have a server-side handler. At a *minimum*, you'd have to serve your Angular app with Node, .NET, etc, that way the /callback route can return a response that renders your Angular app.

Comment: Do you know an online example that would implement this approach you're describing here?

Comment: I prefer using Node so I can stay in TypeScript: https://angular.io/guide/universal